# Linq query to get all values from between two dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Is it possible to use linq to create a query to get a range of values from between two dates used as delimiters?

ex.

Get all entities that have a value of Date column between 12/12/12 and 12/12/13.

I'm only looking for a hint or an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> test(DateTime dt, DateTime dt2)
{
    // check if dt is smaller (or the same) as dt2 and code this out or throw error

    // replace dates with actual class / code
    List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

    return dates.Where(d => d >= dt && d <= dt2);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Of course you can, there is no "between" syntax if that's what you are getting at but it's relatively simple to do e.g.

```
list.Where(x => x.Date >= StartDate && x.Date <= EndDate);
```

If you want better readability, you could even write an extension method for `DateTime` i.e.

```
public static class DateTimeHelpers
{
    public static bool Between(this DateTime dateTime, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        return dateTime >= startDate && dateTime <= endDate;
    }
}
...
list.Where(x => x.Date.Between(StartDate, EndDate));
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved in minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var stuffBetweenDates = ListOfStuff.Where(c => c.Date >= 12/12/12 && c.Date <= 12/12/13);
```

Something along those lines I think. Obviously where I have put 12/12/12 and 12/12/13 you need to put recognized Date Types in those places.

Comment: won't compile I think

Comment: he is only looking for a hint !!